# How to contact a potential graduate supervisor who is on sabbatical?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor

I am trying to manage graduate advisor before I can start my grad school application. There is this particular professor from this university whose research interest aligns with mine. However, this professor is on sabbatical until Dec, 2022 (I am trying to get admitted to fall 23). During this leave the professors takes leave from all kinds of institutional activates (that's what I understood by googling).
Will the professor answer to any graduate position inquiry or should looking for other professor in other university would be ideal option?
What are your suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried their regular university email? Most professors read that even when on sabbatical. f you get no response after a reasonable wait, try @Buffy 's suggestion.

Comment: I've responded to such inquiries, both on and off sabbatical.  But I'm sure other professors have ignored such inquiries even when not on sabbatical.  Both your email/request and the application process itself (e.g., applying to departments vs professors) affect this.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did sent email a professor recently to their university mail who is on sabbatical, and got automatic reply that she is on sabbatical. Yeah, I will give Buffy's suggestion a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you ask their department how they can be effectively connected to. They may need to put you together with the professor.

In most cases, I think a professor would be glad to entertain your request, but you might need to have them pinged from an address they are unlikely to ignore.

I wouldn't ignore the possibility that you can make it happen, but stay flexible.

Comment: Did you mean "can't" make it happen?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, no, but might work that way also.